# elastic search query based on the value of the attributes

Tags: elasticsearch

I have data set as below. Here, We have typeOfProduct, endDate and productDisplayDate attributes. Need to writ query based on the type of product as"ADD", "ADJ", "WTY" and "NEW".

I need to write the query as

```
IF (typeOfProduct === 'WTY') 
    today > endDate

IF (typeOfProduct === 'ADJ' || typeOfProduct === 'ADD') 
    today > productDisplayDate

IF (typeOfProduct === 'NEW')
     NO CONDITION SHOULD DISPLAY ALL

{
    "id": "100",
    "name": "XYZ product",
    "typeOfProduct": "WTY",
    "endDate": "30/08/2020",
    "productDisplayDate": null
},
{
    "id": "101",
    "name": "XYZ1 product",
    "typeOfProduct": "NEW",
    "endDate": "30/08/2020",
    "productDisplayDate": null
},
{
    "id": "101",
    "name": "XYZ1 product",
    "typeOfProduct": "ADJ",
    "endDate": "30/08/2020",
    "productDisplayDate": "30/08/2020",
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query you're after would look like this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "minimum_should_match": 1,
      "should": [
        {
          "terms": {
            "typeOfProduct": [
              "NEW"
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "filter": [
              {
                "terms": {
                  "typeOfProduct": [
                    "WTY"
                  ]
                }
              },
              {
                "range": {
                  "endDate": {
                    "lt": "now"
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "filter": [
              {
                "terms": {
                  "typeOfProduct": [
                    "ADJ",
                    "ADD"
                  ]
                }
              },
              {
                "range": {
                  "productDisplayDate": {
                    "lt": "now"
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```